# How to make counter buttons persistent after page reload

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to implement counter buttons that should be persistent after page reload. Currently my buttons all increment individually but at page, reload only the first/top one is affected. If I click other counter buttons, when I reload page, the first one shows the count of the last button I clicked before I reloaded page. I have buttons for every user I am mapping in the data, but it sees only one button it seems. I need the counter component to dynamically add counter buttons for every user.

I read that one issue with storing state in localStorage at the component level with multiple instances of the same component can lead to unexpected behavior. So I am guessing one solution is using Redux to store the state but I have had no luck implementing it so far. How should I go about doing this?

Here is my button Component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const parsedCount = Number(localStorage.getItem("count") || 0)
    setCount(parsedCount)
  }, [])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("count", count)
  }, [count])

  const handleIncrement = () => {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h5>Count is {count}</h5>
      <button onClick={handleIncrement}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is my App.js where I am calling the counter button:

```
import React from 'react';
import Counter from "./components/Counter";
import './App.css';
import { useAsync } from 'react-async';

function App() {

const loadUsers = async () =>
  await fetch("")
    .then(res => (res.ok ? res : Promise.reject(res)))
    .then(res => res.json())

function App() {
  const { data, isLoading } = useAsync({ promiseFn: loadUsers })
  if (isLoading) return "Loading..."
  if (data)

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div>
      </div>
      {data.map(user=> (
        <div key={user.username} className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <h2>{user.name}</h2>
            <h3>{user.title}</h3>
            <Counter/>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Problem

You are getting the last clicked button value because you are using the same local storage key for every counter.

##### Solution

Add a property to the Counter component to identify every counter:

```
function Counter({id}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const KEY = `count-${id}`;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const parsedCount = Number(localStorage.getItem(KEY) || 0)
    ...
  }, [])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(KEY, count);
  }, [count]);
...
}
```

Use:

```
function App() {

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div>
         <Counter id="counter-1"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h3otu3)

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything. Basically at the moment, only my top counter is working. I have buttons for ever user I am mapping in the data, but it sees only one button it seems. I need the counter component to be dynamically add counter buttons for every user. I will show what my full App looks like in above.

Comment: You can use the user's id or other value to create a counter for every user, and store the counter's value in the localstorage (key per user).

Comment: You mean use user instead of count? Could you show how that looks like syntax-wise?

Comment: @JabbatheHutt see this working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h3otu3...try to reload the page and you will see the counter keeps the value

Comment: I see it works there, but how can I implement it into my App structure? You see here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rws4m3?file=src%2FApp.js  I tried adding the data.map =><Counter id={id}/> but it adds a bunch of buttons and only the top one works.

Comment: Is it because I do not have user id param in the fetched data?

Comment: Yes, try to use the name property or other property, I recommend you to add some unique property to the fetched data.

Comment: Name doesn't seem to work. Do you know how to add a unique property to fetched data?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-oyk3re?file=src%2FApp.js ??

Comment: Ahh, yes I see. I was doing something else. I just assign the id to user.name. Ok thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your state will be refreshed whenever you refresh the browser.
But you can set state within your browser.

```js
localStorage.setItem('abc',1)
```

Above is an example of how we can set the state of `abc` to `1` in the local storage.

After refreshing the page we can do:

```js
abc = localStorage.getItem('abc')
```

And so `abc` will equal `"1"` (note that it will return a string).

As far as your react application goes, when the component is first mounted/initialized, you can read localStorage and update your state accordingly.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I am trying to do. I am trying to make it so all my buttons persist in state after refreshing the page. At the moment only the top button is persistent. When I click the other counter buttons and reload page, they all remain at 0 count and only the first one has the latest count.